# How can I replace an object by its id in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have these serializers:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = AModel
        fields = ('id','name')


class BSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    a = ASerializer(partial=True)
    name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = ‌‌BModel
        fields = ('id','name', 'a')


class CSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    b = BSerializer(partial=True)
    created_by = UserSerializer(required=False) 
    message = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CModel
        fields = ('id','b', 'created_by', 'message')
```

Below is the data,  I send to service:

```
data_json = {
    "id": '1',
    "b": '2',
    "created_by":'3',
    "message": 'Hello world'
}
```

I want the response data to be included of all nested perfect objects, not only nested objects id.

How can I replace a `B` object or `created_by` object by their id in order to creating a `C` object?

Comment: try changing the fields  to `("id", "b__id", "created_by__id", "message")`

Comment: and also you get the id using the full object json like `b['id']`, `crearted_by['id']` when creating the C object

Comment: please try to better explain what you want to do. how should the data_json you want to get look like?

Comment: I want to get data  included with all nested objects, not only nested objects id. @ozren1983

Comment: The question has been updated

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this eventually?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this example, with serializers defined as:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('id', 'name')


class BSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    a = ASerializer(partial=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'a')


class CSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    b = BSerializer(partial=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = C
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'b')
```

And viewset defined as:

```
class CViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = C.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CSerializer
```

And this is example of json returned by above viewset:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "c2",
    "b": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "b2",
            "a": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "a2"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "a3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "b3",
            "a": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "a3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: no dude, doesn't work for POST request with  `b` object's id

Comment: by the way, `b` is not a list of objects. `b` is a single object which i need to replace it by id  :)